# Is it possible to register an Active X .ocx Library using Inno Setup?

Tags: activex, inno-setup

Is it possible to register an Active X .ocx Library using Inno Setup  ?
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Have no idea where to start!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is. And pretty simply. All you need to do is include the [`regserver`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=regserver) flag to your OCX file entry. In script it might look like this:

```
[Files]
Source: "File.ocx"; DestDir: "{sys}"; Flags: regserver
```